# How change the signature of method supporting UIViewController and UIView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

```
public void addStatement(UIButton button , UIViewController/UIView view){

  //view.add(otherView);
}
```

this work with UIViewController but i want to use with UIView as well, how i do for support (UIViewController and UIView) the two ?

Comment: it depends, what you want to do inside of the method. Are you using properties of the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the `addStatement` method like:

```
public void addStatement(UIButton button, UIViewController view)
{
    view.PresentViewController(navController, true, null);
}

public void addStatement(UIButton button, UIView view)
{
    view.add(otherView);
}
```

The compiler will find the correct one, depending on the passed values.

If you have shared functionality, you can do it similar, but call the overloaded methods from the other ones, like:

```
public void addStatement(UIButton button, UIViewController view)
{
    addStatement(button, view.View)
}

public void addStatement(UIButton button, UIView view)
{
    view.add(otherView);
}
```

Comment: but i do not want create 4 functions

Comment: but this is how you do it in C#. And 4 smaller, simpler functions are better than one with 4 if statements.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep it all in one method

```
public void addStatement(UIButton button, UIViewController currentView = null, UIView otherview = null)
    {
        if (otherview != null)
        {
            // do something with otherview
            //return
        }

        if(currentView != null)
        {
            // do something with currentView
            //return
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't do that. It's considered bad practice/design.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean, that answers should suggest solutions, that will lead to other problems (e.g. like bad maintainability).

Comment: True that. I agree.